# ¿Como pongo una imagen de fondo en el pie de página?

Tags: css, css3

Estoy usando Bootstrap y quiero que una imagen de fondo al final de la página, pero no logro que eso suceda, actualmente solo se pone a la altura del último contenido en este caso el texto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código css que estoy utilizando es el siguiente.

```css
body{
    background-image: url('../img/home/backfooter.png');
    background-size: 1000px 500px;
    background-position: bottom center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    
}

body:before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(248,249,250,0.6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Invierte las propiedades del background del body

```
body{
    height: 100%; /* o 100vh */
    background-position: center bottom;
}
```